# go get thrift package failed with repo not found

Tags: go, thrift

Following instruction from the thrift [golang home page](https://thrift.apache.org/lib/go):
trying to run the go get thrift package:
go get git.apache.org/thrift.git/lib/go/thrift/...
getting following error:

```

```
   # cd .; git clone https://git.apache.org/thrift.git godep/src/git.apache.org/thrift.git
Cloning into 
   'godep/src/git.apache.org/thrift.git'...
   fatal: repository 'https://git.apache.org/thrift.git/' not found
   package git.apache.org/thrift.git/lib/go/thrift/...: exit status 128
```

```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a vote to use the Github repos as primary repo, mainly to ease maintenance and contribution. During that process, the old repo has been dropped (intentionally). Unfortunately a few dependencies were overlooked, such as the one you mentioned, plus good communication was not really on our side.

All the dirty details are in [THRIFT-4542](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-4542)

Our PMC Chair also sent out [some more words on that issue](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/thrift-user/201804.mbox/%3CCANyrgvfuRhs-_CgfWpQ2aEwX-uVN859fU%2BzPjxh2xCwr-%2BNAEg%40mail.gmail.com%3E) a few hours ago.

**TL;DR:** We're in the process of fixing this. Sorry for any inconveniences.

---

<sub>"*Shit happens!*" (Forrest Gump)</sub>

Answer (score 3):

It looks like Apache moved thrift to GitHub (but did not update their docs). See their website here: 
https://git.apache.org/thrift.git That thing will return a 404 on your browser too. Instead now they are hosted here https://github.com/apache/thrift

However, if you simply try:

```
go get github.com/apache/thrift
```

Go will complain that there are no `.go` files there.

Instead try:

```
go get github.com/apache/thrift/lib/go/thrift
```

That will pull and compile (tried on go1.10.1, windows/amd64), but I did not try to write a thrift program to verify everything works fine. You might also need to update your imports accordingly to use the github package.